# Trouble querying mongo _id that is a document containing a Date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo collection where the _id values are documents that look like:

```
{
    "_id" :
        {
            "day" : ISODate("2019-02-19T00:00:00Z"),
            "shift_id" : 3,
            "venue_id" : 12345
        }
}
```

I'm having trouble querying because of the ISODate values.  Particularly, when I do a replaceOne with upsert: true, I get an error:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: { venue_id: 12346, shift_id: 13, day: new Date(1551052800000) }
```

It seems to me like the the problem is with the Date objects being unequal to each other, but I'm not sure what I should do to help that.

I'm always using python's **datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 19)** to generate these dates in my _id's.

```
key = {
        'venue_id': 12345,
        'shift_id': 3,
        'day': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 19)
}
document['_id'] = key
collection.replace_one(
    {'_id': key},
    document,
    upsert=True
)
```

Comment: When you resolve `new Date(1551052800000)` to an ISODate, it's returning `ISODate("2019-02-25T00:00:00Z")` (not `ISODate("2019-02-19T00:00:00Z")`). Maybe double check the code that is assigning the `key` value to make sure it's generating what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The object ID in any document is assigned when it is first created and it is [immutable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) so you cannot update it. To change the object ID you would have to insert a new document with the changed ID and them remove the old document. If you don't want users to see the old and new documents at the same time do the insert and remove inside a [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introduction-to-mongodb-transactions-in-python).